# Universal Windows App, cant execute doc.LoadXml(string)

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to retrieve [WOIED](http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/) through an universal windows app using the following code block-

```
    string woeID;
    private string GetWOEID(string zipCode)
    {
        woeID = "";

        XmlDocument woeidData = new XmlDocument();
        string query = String.Format("http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q('{0}')?appid={1}", zipCode, YahooAPI_ID);

        try
        {
            woeidData.LoadXml(query);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        XmlNodeList kk = woeidData.GetElementsByTagName("woeid");
        if (kk.Count != 0)
        {
            woeID = kk[0].InnerText;
            textBox.Text = "";
            GetWeather(); // Calling getweather method.
            return woeID;


        }
        else
        {
            woeID = "";
            textBox.Text = "";
            return woeID;

        }

    }
```

where `zipCode` comes from an `textBox` input and `YahooAPI_ID` is my developer key. I need to retrieve the `WOEID` first to pass it on to `GetWeather()` method to get the weather report in xml from yahoo. But the problem is after `try{woeidData.LoadXml(query);}` it always steps into `catch (exception){}` in debugger. While this code block worked on winform apps before using the code `try {woeidData.Load(query)}`

Any pointers at what I'm doing wrong will be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions.  You need to read the error and find out what's wrong.

Comment: @SLaks How do I do that? I'm pretty novice...

Comment: Just remove your `catch` block, and you'll see the actual error in the debugger.

Comment: @SLaks All i can see is warnings no actual error logs  (post updated with screenshot)

Comment: Reviewing your code you mention you changed it from the [Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx) method to the [LoadXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx).  Why would you do that?

Comment: `Load` worked for winforms app but when I tried to do the same in universal app intellisense pops up `LoadXml` hence I thought I would get away using that. Silly I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is how I did it just in case someone wonders around and stumbled upon this...

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

{
string url = String.Format("http://url");
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync(); 
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            XmlDocument elementdData = new XmlDocument();
            woeidData.Load(reader);
            XmlNodeList element = woeidData.GetElementsByTagName("elementID");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The XmlDocument.LoadXml method is expecting an actually string of xml, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx, not a uri pointing to a resource, you will need to get the contents of the http call seperately.

You could for example use the XmlDocument.Load method, which takes a stream and use a HttpWebRequest https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx and its GetResponse().GetResponseStream() methods to load the xml.

Comment: Hmm I think you are right. But how do I go about and do that?

Comment: In winform app it works though. I mean I can write `XmlDocument.Load(uri)` and it retrieves the xml for me but its not the case for universal app

Comment: Any ideas how do I accomplish this?

Comment: In you example you have LoadXml(uri) not Load(uri).  You are corect though Load() has an overload that can take a http address directly.